# Display point with heighest value in group of points

Tags: qgis, symbology, geometry, expression

I have a point layer with some points to be aggregated by a field named "NumeroNom" (only a substring of it) and I want to display only the point with the highest value of another field named "AmslFt" :

[image]

I tried this :

```
geometry( get_feature( @layer_id, 'AmslFt', maximum("AmslFt", group_by:= substr("NumeroNom", 0, 5))))
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, you will find this expression suitable for you:

```
geometry_n(
    collect(
        expression:=$geometry,
        group_by:=substr("NumeroNom", 0, 5),
        filter:="AmslFt"=maximum("AmslFt", substr("NumeroNom", 0, 5))
        ),
    1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I simplified it with `array_agg($geometry, group_by:= substr("NumeroNom", 0, 5), order_by:= -"AmslFt")[0]`

Comment: Great suggestion! You can put it as a valid answer